# std::cin.clear() fails to restore input stream in a good state

Tags: c++, iostream

In order to test bool i/o, I tried to run this short program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 while(true)
 {
  bool f;
  if (std::cin >> f)
   std::cout << f << '\n';
  else
  {
   std::cout << "i/o error\n";
   std::cin.clear();
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o boolio boolio.cpp
./boolio
0
0
1
1
2
i/o error
-
i/o error
t
i/o error
i/o error
i/o error
... (infinite loop)
```

I wonder why I get an infinite loop when I enter 't', and how to prevent it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line after clearing cin:

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

This way, the stream ignores whatever is left on its buffer.

Comment: That works, thanks. But I still don't understand why '-' or '2' don't require it, while 't' requires it.

Comment: Because a bool is read as a long (unless you use boolalpha), which is then checked for being 0 or 1. Long history, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following combo:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // ignore all characters in the current line

cin.clear(); // restore 'good' flag
```

Using only `cin.ignore()` will discard only one character in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`if (std::cin >> f)` expects either a 0 or 1. And treats all other values as an I/0 error. Even if you enter '-' or 2, `std::cin.ignore()` is still needed.

If you want the program to enter only the values **true or false**, use the following statement instead of `(std::cin >> f)`

`(std::cin >> boolalpha >> f)`