# Resetting the State of a Stream

Tags: c++, state, iostream, conditional-statements

I have a question which is slightly similar to this question on stackoverflow [std::cin.clear() fails to restore input stream in a good state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960399/stdcin-clear-fails-to-restore-input-stream-in-a-good-state), but the answer provided there does not work for me.

The question is: how can I reset the state of a stream to 'good' again?

Here is my code how I try it, but the state is never set to good again. I used both of the lines ignore separately.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int result;
    while ( std::cin.good() )
    {
        std::cout << "Choose a number: ";
        std::cin >> result;

        // Check if input is valid
        if (std::cin.bad())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
        }
        else if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid input: input must be a number." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear(std::istream::failbit);
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "You input the number: " << result << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code here

```
std::cin.clear(std::istream::failbit);
```

doesn't actually clear the failbit, it *replaces* the current state of the stream with `failbit`.

To clear all the bits, just call `clear()`.

---

The description in the standard is a bit convoluted, stated as the result of other functions

> `void clear(iostate state = goodbit);`
>
> *Postcondition:* If `rdbuf()!=0` then `state == rdstate();` otherwise `rdstate()==(state | ios_base::badbit)`.

Which basically means that the next call to `rdstate()` will return the value passed to `clear()`. Except when there are some other problems, in which case you might get a `badbit` as well.

Also, `goodbit` actually isn't a bit at all, but has the value zero to clear out all the other bits.

To clear *just* the one specific bit, you can use this call

```
cin.clear(cin.rdstate() & ~ios::failbit);
```

However, if you clear one flag and others remain, you still cannot read from the stream. So this use is rather limited.

Comment: In my book it says: clear(flag) sets the specified condition state to valid. I interpreted this as: clears the specified error bit. This is incorrect then?

Comment: It is just `clear()` to clear *all* flags. To clear a single flag is a bit more complicated (and not too useful). I have added a new part to my answer.