# Trying again and again to open a file while giving wrong path

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I've just started working on file using C++ for the first time and I would like to write a correct program which allows me to:

1. Open the file giving the path;
2. If it fails to open (showing which error is doesn't matter), ask a new path;
3. Working on the file;
4. Close the file;

The only point I can't do is the second one. I've already tryed somethink like:

```
do{
    cout<<"Path: ";cin>>path;
    f.open(path, ios::in);
}while(f.fail());
```

but if I write the path of an inexisting file and then a path of the file I want to open, the program continously ask me a new path and never stops.

P.S. = Will it be different if I want to use that condition to prevent errors while creating a new file using **ios::out** (for example: a file name/extension which contains illegal characters)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246960/resetting-the-state-of-a-stream

Comment: Call `f.clear()` before the `f.open(path, ios::in);`

Comment: Yes, I've just tried the clear() method before opening the file as mentioned above. It works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the flags if its unsuccessful

```
f.open( path, ios::in ) ;
while( f.fail() )
{
    f.clear();
    std::cout<<"Incorrect file path, Re-Enter ";
    std::cin>>path;
    f.open( path, ios::in ) ;
}
```