# interrogating and controlling state of the stream

Tags: c++, c++14

I am learning C++ Primer 4th edition now and playing with IO stream. When I tried to run the code in the book (Page 289):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int ival;
    // read cin and test only for EOF; loop is executed even if there are
    // other IO failures
    while (cin >> ival, !cin.eof()){
        if (cin.bad())  // input stream is corrupted; bail out
            throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
        if (cin.fail()){
            cerr << "bad data, try again\n";
            cin.clear(istream::failbit);
            continue;
        }
        //ok to process ival
    }
}
```

I met an infinite loop after typing a string (say "as"). So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You say "C++ Primer 4th edition". Please disambiguate by providing an author name (& ideally an ISBN)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a string, extraction into `ival` fails and the *failbit* is set. You then dutifully attempt to clear the bit and continue. But that string is still in the buffer! So the act repeats forever.

Furthermore, [you didn't *actually* clear the bit; you just set the stream state to *failbit*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247530/560648).

You'll need to call just `std::cin.clear()`, then pull out the unexpected data from the buffer before you continue.

<strike>Also, `while (cin >> ival, !cin.eof())` is odd; I haven't checked the behaviour or precedence but I guess you'd just write `while ((cin >> ival) && !cin.eof())`.</strike>

In conclusion, if this is really the code in the book, you need a much better book because the code is wrong in several serious ways. If you're really programming C++14, you need a more up-to-date book anyway since Lippman's C++ Primer wasn't even updated for C++11 until the 5th edition.

Comment: I just tried replacing  cin.clear(istream::failbit) with cin.clear() but it still didn't work. So how can I clear the buffer? I know this book is really old but it still helps. For the comma thing I think "a, b" is an expression that returns b.

Comment: @GuojunZhang: Yeah you have to do _everything_ I said, not just part of it

Comment: @GuojunZhang: Yes, `a, b` evaluates to `b`, but `a << b, c` may not do exactly what you're expecting; depends on the relationship between `<<` and `,`. I don't have time to check right now and my favourite expression checking tool has gone offline :( (`geordi --precedence <expr>`)

Comment: I guess while ((cin >> ival) && !cin.eof()) does not help because when you input a string cin >> ival automatically fails, which is not the goal of the program.

Comment: never mind, I think this piece of code is outdated so I just give up.

Comment: @GuojunZhang: Yeah that's a really good point actually. I didn't spot that.

Comment: @GuojunZhang: hehe okay

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work by adding cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'). This line is necessary because cin.clear() only removes the error flag while the data remains in the buffer. In order to clear the buffer cin.ignore is needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int ival;
    // read cin and test only for EOF; loop is executed even if there are
    // other IO failures
    while (cin >> ival, (!cin.eof())){
        if (cin.bad())  // input stream is corrupted; bail out
            throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
        if (cin.fail()){
            cerr << "bad data, try again" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        }
        //ok to process ival
    }
}
```